# Heroku not running django migrations

Tags: django, heroku

I have a `Django` application that is running on `Heroku`. I am using `Postgres` with `Django` and when I first committed the files and ran `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, the initial migrations worked fine. I then created a new app `restaurant` in which I created a new model.

I ran the local `makemigrations` and `migrate` and it created a new file `restaurant/migrations/0001_initial.py`.

The problem is that when I now run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` it says there are no migrations to apply. I tried

`heroku run python manage.py migrate restaurant`

but there's an error `CommandError: App 'restaurant' does not have migrations.`

I have logged into the console and the migration files are there so I was wondering if I should be doing something like:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I am using the [starter](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template) project as the base and only modified the settings so that

```
DATABASES = {
'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

Comment: First of all, make sure that you have committed your migration files into your repository.

Did you add and then commit your migrations files? Also you shouldn't run `makemigrations` command on heroku you must do it locally.

Comment: As I stated above I have already logged into the heroku console and verified that the files are there.

Comment: But what does that mean? What *exactly* did you do to "verify the files are there"? You didn't list the steps of adding the files to the git repo, committing, and deploying your app; did you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the migrations folder you also need to include `__init__.py` or else `Heroku` will treat the app as not having any migrations.